# Convert CGI to Django framework

Tags: django, httprequest, cgi

Can anyone help me on what approache should be used to convert a CGI script to Django Framework?

I will need to use HTTP Get method request from an HTML Form to obtain user inputs and inject them into a python script.

Here is a sample of CGI python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import cgi, cgitb 
from RTTexec import *
# from RTTexecCustom import *
from globals import *

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

print "Content-Type: text/html" 
print "" 
print "<html>" 
print "<head>" 
print   "<title>RTT</title>" 
print   '<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.css">'
print "</head>" 
print "<body>"
print '<div class="inside">'
print '<p>' 
print "The user entered data are:<br>" 
step = 0

try:    
    execTypeExtract = ''
    execTypeExec = ''
    try:
        execTypeExtract = form["execTypeExtract"].value
    except:
        None
    try:
        execTypeExec = form["execTypeExec"].value
    except:
        None

    try:
        info = form["information"].value
    except:
        None

    if execTypeExtract != '' and execTypeExec != '':
        executionIncludes = execTypeExtract+'_'+execTypeExec
    elif execTypeExtract != '':
        executionIncludes = execTypeExtract
    elif execTypeExec != '':
        executionIncludes = execTypeExec
    else:
        step = 1
    print "<b>execution Includes:</b> " + executionIncludes + "<br>"
```

Comment: No way around it. You'll have to learn Django framework to know how to do what you're trying to do. See the [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/). Anyway, I personally think you should use [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) for this project as it is much faster and easier to get started with.